# Determining if all strings are parsable to int

Tags: c#, validation

I have to loop through a list of `string`s and validate that all are parsable to `int` and not less than 1.  Also, if a string is not parsable but is null or whitespace, then it is OK and my validator should not fail.

Here's the code I have come up with which works fine but leads to method complexity:

```
public static bool ArePerPersonBILimitsInvalid(IEnumerable<string> bilimits)
        {
            return bilimits.Any(c =>
            {
                int d;
                if (!int.TryParse(c, out d))
                {
                    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(c))
                    {
                        return false;
                    }

                       return true;
                }

                if (d < 1)
                {
                    return true;
                }

                return false;
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I find that negatives in method names lead to confusing code. For instance,

```
if (!ArePerPersonBILimitsInvalid(...))
```

> "Are there no BI limits that are invalid?"

becomes much more readable when we write it this way:

```
if (ArePerPersonBILimitsValid(...))
```

> "Are all BI limits valid?"

So let's fill in the blanks.

```
public static bool ArePerPersonBILimitsValid(IEnumerable<string> biLimits)
{
    return biLimits.All(IsBILimitValid);
}
```

Great, so now we need to write `IsBILimitValid`.

```
public static bool IsBILimitValid(string biLimit)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(biLimit))
    {
        return true;
    }

    int value;
    return int.TryParse(biLimit, out value) && value >= 1;
}
```

This way the code much more closely reflects your problem statement:

> loop through a list of strings and validate that all are parsable to
>   int and not less than 1

Comment: @Heslacher, no I meant "more readable (when written) as"... perhaps I should have said, "is less readable *than*".

Comment: Still a "negative" with `!int.TryParse`. I'd go with `return int.TryParse(biLimit, out value) && value >= 1;` but it's debatable, if that's more readable.

Comment: @Corak that's a nice version, mind if I use that in my answer? My note about negatives was just in relation to method names, e.g. `IsValid` vs `IsInvalid`, `HasErrors` vs `HasNoErrors`.

Comment: @mjolka - not at all ^_^. I try to avoid the `!something` notation wherever possible (and feasible), because it's so easy to miss the `!`. I even use `something == false` sometimes to really make it obvious (but of course, never ever `something == true`).

Comment: @mjolka Just a note.  Did you mean !ArePerPersonBILimitsInvalid(...) is not as readable as ArePerPersonBILimitsValid(...)

Comment: @dreza thanks, I thought it was clear but getting two questions on that point meant it wasn't! I've tried to improve the wording.

Answer (score 7):

As per my interpretation, you don't need empty string check inside the if clause you can put it out side, and last condition could be expressed in one line.

```
return bilimits.Any(inputstring =>
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(inputstring))
        return false;

    int parsedNumber;
    if (!int.TryParse(inputstring, out parsedNumber))
        return true;

    return parsedNumber < 1;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's that really bad, but you could simplify it by doing it all in one statement.

```
public static bool ArePerPersonBILimitsInvalid(IEnumerable<string> bilimits)
{
    return bilimits.Any(c =>
    {
        int asInt;
        return (int.TryParse(c, out asInt) && asInt < 1) ||
                !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(c);
    });
}
```

Some of the other answers I actually like.  I'll just provide this as an alternative.

Comment: You don't need to initialize `asInt`, it's definitely assigned in all code after `TryParse()`.

Comment: @svick true, just habit I think.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static bool ArePerPersonBILimitsValid(this IEnumerable<string> biLimits)
{
    int intResult;
    var invalidResults = biLimits.Where(s => {
            if (int.TryParse(s, out intResult))
                return false;
            else
                return !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s);
        });
    return invalidResults.Count() == 0;
}

string[] inValidTestIntegers = new string[] { "10", "12", "str" });
string[] balidTestIntegers = new string[] { "10", "12" });
bool isValid1 = inValidTestIntegers.ArePerPersonBILimitsValid();
bool isValid2 = balidTestIntegers.ArePerPersonBILimitsValid();
```

//output:
false
true